# nginx reverse load assets from foo.bar/app properly

Tags: docker, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

i have a webapplication running in a docker container behind nginx reverse proxy on the same container network.
the nginx is set up so that `foo.bar/app` redirect to the container but application seems to try load resources from `foo.bar/`. i have tried to do what is documented here:https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/likeapache/
as a result my location block looked like this:

```
location /app {
        root /app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://webapp/;
    }
```

where webapp is the name of the webapp's docker container in the network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the location block this is fine

```
location /app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://webapp/;
    }
```

the trick is to access with a trailing slash so with `foo.bar/app/` rather than with `foo.bar/app`
additionally adding this line will add the trailing slash automagically:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent
```